# Does it matter how my html/css is written, or does it just matter if it validates?

Tags: html

When I write html and css, does it matter if I do things "my way", like using an abundance of absolute positioning, or maybe coming up with very unorthodox solutions to certain problems like layout? Since I'm not great right at markup right now, I am kind of just "doing what works." I'm reading as much as I can but I know I am making mistakes. Is it important that I pay extra special attention to exactly how I'm writing it so I don't develop bad habits, or should I just be happy that it validates and that is the most important thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do more than validate. It has to look good, or at least be functional. The only way to truly validate that is via extensive testing.

It's worth noting that the standard patterns are there for a reason—because they work. But they're certainly not gospel. Metaphorically speaking, there's more than one way to skin a cat. There's no reason for too much hand-wringing if you find alternative solutions that work for you. The only real concern is that your code might be more difficult to understand and/or maintain in the future, either by you or by someone else.

Above all, though, the best way to learn and improve is to practice. And there's no better way to practice and discover your mistakes by writing and shipping actual code. If you make a mistake, chalk it up to experience. That's what we all do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's somewhere in the middle. It's important to always ask yourself "is this the best way to write this", but it's equally important to not get too hung up worrying about the perfect way to do things and just ship code. The more experience you get by getting stuff out there on the web in people's hands, the better position you'll be in to know what "the best way to do things" is.

Answer (score 0):

It will all start to matter once other user has to maintain your code.

You should watch these videos. http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/

Comment: Thanks for that link. I'm watching them right now. They are golden nuggets of information for a noob like me.

Comment: They actually tell you how you should manager your CSS, Javascript & HTML.

Answer (score 0):

"should I just be happy that it validates" I would say `never`. If your code is working well doesn't mean that it is setting upto the mark.And the best way of knowing you have done correct coding or not is check your HTML pages in all the available browsers/in different OS with different screen resolutions etc. You may like to see what are the standards defined (however may vary depending upon your application needs) for CSS and HTML. So try to learn those things instead of doing it in "your way". Here is one reference for you.

[Standards HTML/CSS](http://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/htmlcss)

Comment: THanks so much for that link, checking it out now